# How to make SELECTION SORT using ASP Classic or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

How to make SELECTION SORT using ASP Classic or jQuery?

Comment: Seriously? This is the best you can do?

Comment: What kind of SELECTION SORT are you looking for and why? class assignment?

Answer (score 0):

ASP is a server-side language. jQuery is a client-side enhancement for JavaScript. Apples and oranges.

The easiest way is to sort your list on the server. Assuming you are populating your list for a database query, simply modify the query to sort the results in the order you want.